# Should a model be created to support a repository reading a database view intended for a UI pick list?

Tags: c#, wpf, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

I am looking for solution(s) to providing a pick list in an application based on a domain model. I Have a Product model with a Product Repository. I have a UI which needs to display a pick list of Products. The pick list would only need to display 2 properties from a Product Model which has 15 properties.

I am thinking of creating a database view named ProductSummaries where each row in this view would be represented by a new Model called ProductSummary.  This database view would be drawn from the Products table which is used for Product models.

Because this would be a database view, the creation of a repository for the ProductSummary model would only need one data access method which would be GetAll(). No modifications would be allowed on ProductSummaries because they are from a database view based on the Products table.

What other solutions are used to provide pick lists based on some properties of an existing domain model in an application? I don't know if what I am thinking of doing is something that will lead to problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if what I am thinking of doing is something that will lead to problems.

What you've come very close to discovering on your own is [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs) -- the pattern of having one object to support queries that is separate from the object used to support mutations.

You should be fine, so long as you make it clear in your code that the Product Summaries are read only.  (For example, if you use marker interfaces, then the summaries should be marked like *values* rather than like *aggregates*).

Comment: What I tend to implement for the *read model* is a *query* layer.  I could, for instance, have a `Product` aggregate with its corresponding `IProductRepository`.  The aggregate would have all the *command* side of things implemented.  I then have a `IProductQuery` that would return either primitives, a `DataRow` or `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, or sometimes even a DTO.  In the case of a DTO you may go with `ProductSummary` or even `Product`.  I tend to namespace the query objects under a `Query` namespace to make the distinction apparent.